# Converting all args to a bytes array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello guys I'm new to java and I've been toying with it, right now I'm trying to convert all entry's in "args" (Arguments) to an a byte array so that I can have raw bytes to look at... right now I'm trying to do this:

```
int bytePointer=0;
int argsPointer=0;  

byte[] ourMessage = new byte[80];

while(args.length>=argsPointer)
{
    ourMessage[bytePointer] = args[argsPointer].getBytes();
    argsPointer++;

    bytePointer = bytePointer + args[argsPointer].length();
    bytePointer++;
}
```

Within a loop However javas giving my the error "byte[] cannot be converted to byte". I can't seem to find a method to do this however, all my searches have led me to something else?

Comment: What does `getbytes()` return and what is a `ourMessage[index]` ?  You're trying to assign an array of bytes to a single byte.  (Also, for the sake of naming, it's not actually a pointer it's an index into an array.  We don't do pointers in Java (as one would in C/C++).)

Comment: Please show the declarations of all variables involved.

Comment: assuming `args` is an array of String (standard entry point argument), `getBytes()` returns an array of bytes.

Comment: Food for thought - Won`t (args.length>=argsPointer) always throw an IndexOutOfBounds?

Comment: Use `getBytes(charsetName)` instead of `getBytes()` which relies on the default character set, unless you really know you want the results to vary depending on the current default character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fill the `ourMessage` array with the array from `args[argsPointer].getBytes()` one at a time:

```
while(args.length>=argsPointer)
{
    byte[] argBytes = args[argsPointer].getBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i < argBytes.length; i++, bytePointer++) {
        ourMessage[bytePointer] = argBytes[i];
    }
    argsPointer++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so basically what I was trying to do would have created an overflow within a byte...

Answer (score 0):

`args[argsPointer].getBytes()` returns an array of bytes, so you can't assign it to a single byte.

While you can use an internal loop to copy the individual bytes (as suggested in the other answer), I think it would be more efficient to use [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) :

```
int argsPointer = 0;
int offset = 0;
while(argsPointer < args.length)
{
    byte[] source = args[argsPointer].getBytes();
    argsPointer++;
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, ourMessage, offset, source.length);
    offset += source.length;
}
```

Of course, you should check that `ourMessage` is large enough to hold all those bytes.